# how to toggle each button separately on multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have same button for multiple times each one have same work that is of hide and show. I have to toggle following data after click on that button

```
<button type="button" class="pull-right btn menu">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<ul class="downmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

and js code is

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
    $('.downmenu').toggle('show');
    });
    });
```

my problem is that after click on any button all buttons are working. How to toggle each separately. I have to toggle downmenu ul list on each button so how can i do it?

Comment: You have only once `downmenu` what do you mean by each?

Comment: @Satpal i have that same button on multiple times, i want to toggle that downmenu on each button seperately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop inside the click event is redundant. The problem is the global selector for `.downmenu` which selects all elements with that class. The solution is to isolate the element `.downmenu` next to the button clicked:

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.downmenu').toggle('show');
});
```

Comment: where is `"show"` documented as valid argument for `toggle()`?